# Apparently a record is getting deleted twice

Tags: trigger, contact, merge

I have the following AFTER DELETE trigger:

```
trigger ContactMergeTrigger on Contact (after delete) {

    List<Merge__c> newMergeRows = new List<Merge__c>();

    for(Contact contact : trigger.old) {
        if(String.isNotBlank(contact.MasterRecordId)) { 
            newMergeRows.add(new Merge__c(LoserId__c = contact.Id, WinnerId__c = contact.MasterRecordId));  
        }         
    }

    if(newMergeRows.size() > 0) {
        insert newMergeRows;
    }

}
```

And after 2 years of running smoothly, today we saw this error:

> 2016-07-01T07:07:22-04:00,,"Merge Call
>   Failure",,,,,,,"Msg:ContactMergeTrigger: execution of
>   AfterDeletecaused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate
>   value found: LoserId__c duplicates value on record with id:
>   a1S13000002WHvm: []Trigger.ContactMergeTrigger: line 12,
>   column 1 StatusCode:49 Fields:   " 2016-07-01T07:07:22-04:00,Single
>   Table Dedupe,"Dedupe complete",,,,,,,""
>   2016-07-01T07:07:22-04:00,Single Table Deduper,"Batch
>   Dedupe",Contact,,,,,,"0 Contact objects were merged into 0
>   Contact(s)There were 1 errors.”

It appears that LoserId is already in the Merge table. How is this possible?

EDIT: is it possible for a record to become a merge loser more than once? e.g. via undelete?

Comment: Maybe some user undeleted and deleted again? It doesn't look like you're handling the undelete possibility.

Comment: I agree, that seems like a reasonable potential cause at the moment. I think I have to test that and see if it reproduces the error.

Comment: Or it is dataloader job which had the same contact twice?

Comment: You don't need to check `size() > 0`. System does not consume any dml if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities for this error,

> 1. Field "LoserId__c" has been made unique. Check definition of this field.
> 2. A Validation rule has been written that checks for the duplicate value of this field.
>
>    3. At last check if the is any other trigger on object that checks for duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error in a Sandbox by undeleting a merge loser and then trying to merge that record again. This looks like a very likely culprit for my issue.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like it should maybe be a comment on the other answer? It looks like a post that is likely to get deleted.